# C++ - Big-O Notation

Tags: c++, big-o

For some reason im unable to solve this.
what will be the Big-o Notation

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        c[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
```

Comment: Please tell me you format your code better than this in real life!

Comment: Steven, if we simply tell you what the complexity is, you're not going to learn how to compute the complexity. Please suggest what you think the complexity is and why. Then we can better help you.

Comment: @Oli: Before I edited it, it had absolutely no indentation whatsoever (only newlines) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  c[i][j] = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
 }
```

It looks like it's `O(n^3)` because it has 3-level loops.

Comment: 3 levels of loops. Each go to N. Each goes up by 1. Pretty clear o(n^3) to me, but it's been too long since college....

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                  // N times
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {            // N times (
        c[i][j] = 0;                         // Constant plus
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)          // N times
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];    // Constant
    }                                        // )
```

Or O(*n* · *n* · (1 + *n* · 1)) which is equivalent to O(*n* · *n* · *n*) or O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) after collapsing the constant operations.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: O(n^3)

Because the outer most loop executes N times.
For each element in that loop the middle loop executes N times.
For each element in the middle loop, the inner most loop executes N times.

Total looping is N*N*N = N^3

This statement executes N^2 times  `c[i][j] = 0;` but it is irrelevant compared to the inner most statement which executes N^3 times.

Answer (score 0):

The way to work this out is to calculate the number of operations in terms of `n`, and then discard less-significant terms (if there are any)...